# jQuery Dynamically Updating Fields Scrolls Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form a user fills out, clicks "save" and it gets moved down into a table. From there they can edit a row or delete it.

However, every time something is added or removed from the table, or the fields are re-populated from the table back into the form (and thus removed from the table until being saved again) the page jumps back up to the top.

So every time a user updates this area, they have to scroll back down, and it's a pretty big form. I have most of the sections in a collapse but like myself I suspect the users will leave them open as they move down.

Does anyone know what causes this and if there are any really simple ways to avoid it? I'm super new to jQuery, and even JS, having spent most of my time server-side.

**Edit: Adding HTML:**

```
<div class="scroll">
    <table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered scroll">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Product</th>
                <th colspan="2">Units</th>
                <th>Pieces</th>
                <th>UOM</th>
                <th>NMFC</th>
                <th>Hazmat</th>
                <th>class</th>
                <th>weight</th>
                <th>L</th>
                <th>W</th>
                <th>H</th>
                <th>Cube</th>
                <th>Density</th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="productTable">
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Post HTML code where you have tables containing data which you fill into the form

Comment: <tbody id="productTable"></tbody> Is where all the <TR>s go that hold data. They're all added/removed dynamically. To edit a row, it's removed and then added again as a new row.

Comment: how do you submit the form?

Comment: When the page jumps? the user clicks on table data or when saving back to table?

Comment: @InTry The form is never "submitted" a click event is 'bound' to the save, edit, and delete buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$(SAVE/EDIT).click(function () {

  // your code 

  return false; //add this
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The most likely culprit is that your actual elements are changing in height, causing the page containing the elements to resize to fit them. From there, this can look like a scrolling action.

On this JSFiddle, try making a lot of elements in the table, then click them to remove them and put them back in the form. You'll see that once you have enough elements, the page will scroll.

http://jsfiddle.net/turiyag/VUqCB/3/

I'm betting that the way you've implemented table updates is to delete the whole table and rebuild it? If so, try doing the incremental updates exemplified in the JSFiddle:

```
$(function() {
    $(":button").click(function(event) {
        //Make a new table row (but don't insert it just yet
        var newTableRow = $("<tr/>");

        //For every textbox, add a corresponding data column to the new table row
        $.each($(":text"), function(index, obj) {
            //Store the id of the textbox the data is from in the "from" attribute.
            newTableRow.append('<td from="' + $(this).prop("id") + '">' + $(this).val() + '</td>');
        });
        //Append the row to the table
        newTableRow.appendTo("table");
        //When the row is clicked
        newTableRow.click(function() {
            //$(this) refers to the row element here
            //For every child element (td element)
            $.each($(this).children(),function(index, obj) {
                //$(this) refers to the td element here
                //In the textbox with the id we previously stored in the from attribute
                //Set the value of that textbox to the value of this td
                $("#" + $(this).attr("from")).val($(this).text());
            });
            //$(this) refers to the row element here
            $(this).remove();
        });
        //Reset the form
        //$("form")[0].reset();
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Rebuilding the entire table would be too much jQuery effort than I'm willing to commit to.

When a user edits the row, the row's data is re-populated into the form then $('#row_1').remove() and then I just add the row back when they save it again with a new ID.

I'm sure the page would scroll once enough elements were added, but the I chose the previous answer because the 'jump' was happening even just populating fields (from a backend API to search contacts) and return false; resolved all jumping issues.