# jQuery $.change works In one place, but not another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically, if any of the text field are changed in a specific DIV, I want to empty the HTML from another DIV.

HTML:

```
<div class="row">

<div class="span4">

    <h3 class="heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#shipper">Shipper Information</h3>

    <div class="bg-light collapse in bg-light" id="shipper">

        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="shipper_name" />

        <label>Address 1</label>
        <input type="text" id="shipper_address1" />

        <label>Address 2</label>
        <input type="text" id="shipper_address2" />

        <label>City</label>
        <input type="text" id="shipper_city" />

        <label>State</label>
        <input type="text" id="shipper_state" />

        <label>Zip</label>
        <input type="text" id="shipper_zip" /> 

    </div>

</div>

<div class="span4">

    <h3 class="heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#consignee">Consignee Information</h3>

    <div class="bg-light collapse in bg-light" id="consignee">

        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="consignee_name" />

        <label>Address 1</label>
        <input type="text" id="consignee_address1" />

        <label>Address 2</label>
        <input type="text" id="consignee_address2" />

        <label>City</label>
        <input type="text" id="consignee_city" />

        <label>State</label>
        <input type="text" id="consignee_state" />

        <label>Zip</label>
        <input type="text" id="consignee_zip" />

    </div>

</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$('#shipper').find('input:text').change(function(){
    alert('I changed.');
    carriersClear('Shipper Details Changed');
    return false;
});

$('#consignee').find('input:text').change(function(){
    alert('I changed.');
    carriersClear('Consignee Details Changed');
    return false;
});
```

The `#consignee` version works fine, `#shipper` does not which makes no sense since they're basically identical.

I don't get any errors in my console, either.

**EDIT: I had another Div called shipper. (Yes. I'm an idiot.)**
A lesson for everyone: Ctrl+F can be your best friend.

Comment: try clearing your browser cache and try again...

Comment: They are working in the Fiddle I just made... http://jsfiddle.net/EZJ6w/1/

Comment: `$('input[type="text"]', '#shipper').on('change', function() { ... })`

Comment: I bet this issue is with the `carriersClear` method

Comment: Why the return false? http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/

Comment: It seems like if I don't return false from damn near everything, the page jumps to the top. Rather than waiting to find out if the page is going to jump without a return false, I just return false from everything.

Comment: The page jumps to the top with `a` tags linked to a `#`. In that case use `e.preventDefault`, while passing `e` or `event` into your function like so: `function(e) { e.preventDefault() }`

Comment: @DavidScherer Oh boy, that's not a good reason at all. Don't you think it would be beneficial to learn what `return false;` does and use it appropriately? `return false;` is the equivalent of having `event.preventDefault();` and `event.stopPropagation();` in your function. `preventDefault` prevents the default behavior of the control (an `<a>` navigating to a new URL, a button submitting a form, etc.). `stopPropagation` stops the event from bubbling up the DOM. For example, when you click a button on the page, it triggers for the button, and all of its parents/ancestors (up to `document`)

Comment: @adeneo How is your code any better/different?

Comment: @adeneo Haha well an explanation would be better for the OP. I think delegation would be preferred anyways - `$("#shipper").on("change", "input[type=text]", function () {});`. Your selector is preferred, since browsers can take advantage of it being a CSS selector. And the use of `on` is nice, but not necessarily better (I prefer it, I'm just saying).

Comment: @Ian Isn't there some disagreement on whether to use $('#ident tag[attr="val"').func() or $('tag[attr="val"]', '#ident')?

Comment: @DavidScherer Well, yes, because they accomplish the same thing, but are carried out differently. jQuery will have to parse `'#ident tag[attr="val"]'`, when it is much easier for it to know what needs to be done with something like `$('tag[attr="val"]', '#ident')`. At the same time, `'$('tag[attr="val"]', '#ident')` is the same as `$('#ident').find('tag[attr="val"]')` and is what I prefer to use

Comment: @Ian I didn't say it was good. As for how 'beneficial' it would be, I consider that debatable. It takes a lot of will power each day not to go searching for the nearest overpass. I like PHP. It's my comfort zone, it's where I rock. Front-end, well that's a whole other story. It scares me, to say the least. I may eventually get a JQ book since I'm doing a lot of it these days, but currently I'm learning as I go. (it would have been nice if the person had mentioned the event stuff when telling me about return false, though, instead of just writing "add return false"). Anyway, thanks. :)

Comment: If I remember correctly `input:text` is deprecated, and `input[type="text"]` should be used. Personally I just like the context selector over `find()` for simple situations, even if it's a millisecond slower. And I see no apparent reason for using delegated event handlers here ?

Comment: @DavidScherer You're very right. I just think it would've made sense to ask someone (even here on SO) about the use of `return false;` or look it up. I understand though - it was working for you, so no worrying. But usually when you do something but don't know why, you might want to figure it out (not find a near overpass). No big deal though, just wanted to explain. As you work with jQuery more, obviously come here with any questions!

Comment: @adeneo I don't know if it's deprecated (I can't find anywhere that says it is, but I may be looking in the wrong places). But still, `input[type=text]` is suggested. The whole use of context/`.find` is mainly a preference, I just think it's more readable and logical, but it ends up doing the same thing. I just really don't like long string selectors. And there's no big reason to use event delegation, but 2 event handlers are "better" than 12. Again, an area of preference

Comment: @Ian Sadly it was in one of my SO questions (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14753826/jquery-dynamically-updating-fields-scrolls-page) that I learned the return false 'trick'.

Comment: @DavidScherer Ahh I see. Yes, a very poor answer, although it fixes what you needed. So for those kind of answers, just ask for an explanation before accepting it (even if it did solve your question). Anyways, hopefully my explanation helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is with the `carriersClear()`. But this works:

```
$('input[type="text"]', '#shipper').on('change', function(){
    console.log("I changed.");
    carriersClear('Shipper Details Changed');
    //No need to return false.
});

$('input[type="text"]', '#consignee').on('change', function(){
    console.log("I changed.");
    carriersClear('Consignee Details Changed');
});
```

This will also work:

```
//Here we assign only one event handler to #consignee.
$('#consignee').on('change', 'input[type="text"]', function(e){
    console.log("I changed.");
    carriersClear('Consignee Details Changed');
});
```

I suggest you watch [this video](http://training.bocoup.com/screencasts/more-efficient-event-handlers/) on event handlers for a better understanding.

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EZJ6w/4/)

Comment: All carriersClear() does is (when I uncomment it for testing to see what cleared the carriers) is alert the message passed to it, and then it does $('#carriers').html('');

As I said, it works for the #consignee div, but not the #shipper div

Comment: What browser are you using? I tested the code in my answer with the latest Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: I'm using FF 19. The #shipper div still does not work.

Comment: Does the Fiddle I posted work in your browser?

Comment: I had another #shipper div elsewhere in the document.

Comment: While this answer didn't technically solve the problem (since the problem itself was PEBK) I am currently using this version of the code.