# Un-reproducible issue with IE 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-propagation

Basically, I have a ton of JQ that runs fine on every browser, including IE 9/10. I asked a sales rep to test something today, and their computer has IE 9 on it.

When the user clicks a button that populates HTML into a table, the page jumps to the top. I know this is caused by event propagation (My other SO Post: [jQuery Dynamically Updating Fields Scrolls Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14753826/jquery-dynamically-updating-fields-scrolls-page)). So I return false everywhere this is applicable (or use event.stopPropagation(), depending.).

However, when this one user loads the page, this issue surfaces again.

Are there settings I should check (note the JS works, the page just jumps so it shouldn't be a problem with having JS disabled) or should I just write this off as "Nobody know what the hell you did to your browser but it can't be reproduced anywhere else"?

I'm just at a loss, and this is the most I've done with JQ or UI development ever (I like to stick to the backend of things) so I'm not sure of any quirks to look for or anything.

If there's anything I can do to make this question more coherent, just let me know and I'll try. I know there's not much to go off of, but I don't know where to start.

Comment: To answer that question, we would really need to see some code or a link to the application.  There are so many reasons that could cause this issue.  Did you ask if (s)he encounters any JS errors in the console?  Are all JS libraries loaded correctly?  Are some libraries hosted somewhere else than the main page (i.e. behind a firewall that prevents the user from accessing it)

Comment: So that button has a `href` attribute and is a link actually?

Comment: Yeah, it's a Twitter BS Anchor button `<a class="btn btn-primary...`.

Comment: I was just back to this user's office, and tested this myself, in an attempt to reproduce the issue and capture output from the console, but everything worked fine. It makes sense if a JS file failed to load, but shouldn't having everything encapsed in `$(document).ready(function(){...})` prevent code from running when files don't load, effectively leaving the document "Not ready"?

Comment: Do you change assets names on each deployment? -> what about IE caching your JS. Is he testing in a company with proxy caching which could ignore the asset version you set after "?" in your assets urls. You confirm there is no JS errors?

Comment: There are no errors showing in the console on any of the browsers I've been testing with (IE FF Chrome, all those we know our customer's use). As for asset versions, I'm not sure I follow, you'll have to explain it to me like a two year old I imagine. I'm not a front end guy by trade (I'm just good at learning things) so I'm confused.

This user is accessing the site from the same location as myself, on our staging server.

Comment: You say that "there are no errors showing in the console on any of the browsers I've been testing with"... That is not really at issue here... the question is: Are there JS errors in the browser that displays the problem. If there are JS errors, they might be a good clue in what is causing the problem.

Comment: @Steve No, I can't find any errors. Not in the affected browser (which is no longer affected for some reason) or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not caused by event propagation, but by the default action of the button. Instead of calling `.stopPropagation()`, you should be calling `.preventDefault()`.

Comment: I'm returning false so that should call stoppropagation preventDefault and the other one.

Comment: Yes, According to [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/), `return false` triggers both. If you have done that correctly, there must be some other error - but you'll need to show us some code.